# Lifetime estimate of components where only a fraction has failed so far?

Tags: probability

I am attempting to calculate how long a component is expected to last and ultimately how many working components will be left at a future point in time.

800 have failed and 2200 are still working. I have calculated the Kaplan Meier estimator, but this does not give me the full survivor function as many components are working longer than the longest lifetime of the failed components.

I could use the current Kaplan Meier estimator to calculate the future life of components younger than the longest failure time. But how to calculate the values for the older components? Or the total count of surviving components in the future?

[image]

Comment: The figure of 800 failures out of (a total of) 3000 does not seem "a relatively small amount" on which to forecast component lifetimes (half-lifes in service?).  Your Question raises the issue of "the censoring of the data" but provides no information about what kind of censoring has occurred.

Comment: Censoring in the sense that there are many components that have not yet failed and by that I don't have their time of failure yet.

Comment: That is not "censoring of the data".  Censoring (in statistics) refers to where data sampling is affected by removal of information beyond the control of those conducting a study.  Knowing that 2200 components are still working after a known time-in-service is not missing information but rather positive information that helps to characterize the distribution of time-to-failure.

Comment: Thank you, I have removed the reference to censoring, and tried to improve the question